# How to set auto width on fixed and centred element?

Tags: css

How do I set this bottom div to be wide as it can be just so that the text don't go in new line? 
Basically I am trying to set Cookie notice to be in position fixed, in the center of a page with its child elements vertically aligned in same line.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmVVPr

```
<div class="fixed">
  Lorem ispum dolor sita ametad asdf asdfLorem ispum dolor sita ametad asdf asdf sita ametad asdfispum dolor sita ametad 
  <a class="link" href="#">Link</a>
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>

.fixed {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you could wrap your content in a inner `div`, like I did in the snippet below. Also I adjusted the CSS according.

```js
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429112/how-to-set-auto-width-on-fixed-and-centred-element/43429243#
```

```css
.container {
  width: 950px;
  margin: auto;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.fixed .container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 7px;
  left: 50%;
  width: auto;
}

.fixed  .link {
  margin-left: 1em;
  color: #fff;
}
.fixed  .btn {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>
  Lorem ispum dolor sita ametad asdf asdfLorem ispum dolor sita ametad asdf asdf
</h1>

  <p>
    Lorem ispum dolor sita ametad asdf asdfLorem ispum dolor sita ametad asdf asdf
  </p>
</div>

<div class="fixed">
  <div class="container">
    Lorem ispum dolor sita ametad asdf asdfLorem ispum dolor sita ametad asdf asdf sita ametad asdfispum dolor sita ametad 
    <a class="link" href="#">Link</a>
    <button class="btn">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change one property from your CSS. And you are almost there.

```
.fixed {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 100%;
}
```

Instead of setting `width:auto;` set it to `width:100%` then if you want to make your content inside `fixed` div to be centered then you can set it according to your test using `padding`. Hope it helps.